React Component Not Scrolling to Element with scrollIntoView or Anchor Tag
I'm working on a React and TailwindCSS project where I have a form that, upon submission, should smoothly scroll to a loading skeleton indicator. However, the scrolling isn't working as expected.
Below are the two methods I've tried without success:
1. Using scrollIntoView in JavaScript:
I tried to scroll to the element using scrollIntoView within my form submission handler:
const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(formRef.current);
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
  const result = await handleSubmit(data);
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (skeletonRef.current) {
      skeletonRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  }, 100);  // here im delaying to ensure that the skeleton is rendered
};


2. Using an HTML anchor tag with href:
I also attempted to wrap the submit button in an  tag with an href pointing to an ID, expecting a traditional HTML anchor behavior:
<a href="#loading-skeleton">
  <button type="submit" className="...">
    Generate
  </button>
</a>

With the target element as:
{loading && (<div id="loading-skeleton" ref={skeletonRef} className="...">
  {/* Skeleton content */}
</div>)}

and thanks for ur help!

Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code seems okay. A minimal reproducible example will help solve the problem

Unfortunately, both methods I've tried are not working. which method you recommend to implement and debug ?
